# upgrading ruby on OSX 10.7 for zurb foundtion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, zurb-foundation-5

Hi guys been trying to get zurb foundation installed on my system again unfortunately im having issues. Im running OSX 10.7 because i have an older system and had to wipe after i installed yosemti mistakenly, before I had 10.8 and didn't seem to be having issues. It seems like I can get the ruby update to work, ive tried home brew and rvm, and now at least when i check ruby version it says 2.2 but looks like foundation is still trying to use 1.8. ALso would it be the OS and maybe I should wipe again and go back to OSX 10.8?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem foundation (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/foundation:18
```

Comment: At the moment i haven't more precise advices but check your $PATH.

Comment: im not great with $PATH how to do that again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This A List Apart post by Olivier Lacan, is very helpful in understanding the $PATH variable: http://alistapart.com/article/the-path-to-enlightenment.

In short, in the terminal, after your prompt, type:

```
echo $PATH
```

The result will show you your $PATH. It may look something like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: can you explain what that means and repressents pleasse.

Comment: The results of echoing `$PATH` show that variable's value; which is, in this case, a colon delimited list that points to different directories in your computer. It is parsed from left to right by various applications that need to access data stashed in those places. If the Path is jumbled up, a significant directory may not be referenced. The Path is found iinside .bash_profile, a hidden file (note that dot before the name). It's found in your home directory. The other directories in the list are elsewhere on your system. That blog post really explains it better than I'm able to. Sorry.